# iOS UITextField difference between addTarget and textFieldDidEndEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

What's the difference between adding a target with the `.editingDidEnd` option and the method `textFieldDidEndEditing`?

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField! {
    didSet {
        // check when textField editing ends
        textField.addTarget(self,
                            action: #selector(titleDidChange(_:)),
                            for: .editingDidEnd)
    }
}
```

VS.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // user has resigned responder
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result is the same. Both are called when a text field is no longer the first responder.

But the use of `addTarget` allows multiple targets to be notified about the event while the use of the `delegate` method only allows a single target to be notified of the event.

If you only have one target and you are also implementing other delegate methods, then just use the delegate method.

If you need multiple targets to know about the event, then you need to use `addTarget`.

Comment: When I add a print statement to each I noticed that addTarget gets called after the delegate method. Is there a reasons they are called one of the other?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. If you use both, both will be called.